# client side and server side not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a big problem with my client side and my server side and I need help.
I  have to **gather data from two forms and submit data after validation** when the saveentry button of the third form is pressed but I am getting confused. The values do not get displayed and server side validation does not work. I have two forms which have to undergo client side and server side validation. I use the `onsubmit` so that when the form is posted the values are checked this is the code:

```js
function validation() {
  person_name = $('#person_name').val();
  if (test_name == '') {
    $('#test_name').parent().append('<div class="error">Please fill this field</div>');
    errors = true;
  }
  if (errors) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var personname = ("<h1>" + person_name + "</h1>");
    $('#display').append('<div class = "display">' + personname + '</div>');

  }
}
```

```js
function validation1(){
  var product_name = $('#product_name').val();
  if(product_name == ''){
    $('#product_name').parent().append('<div class="error">Please fill this field</div>');
    // the other fields are validated as well
    errors = true;     
  } 
  if(errors){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    // the values are appended to display
  }
}
```

The forms look like this

```html
<form name = "person" action = "" onsubmit= "return validation" method=" post" >
  <input type="text" name = "personname" id = "personname">
</form>

<form name = "products" action = "" method = "post" onsubmit= "return   validation1">
  <input type="text" name = "productname" id = "productname">
  <input type="text" name = "company" id = "company">
  <input type="text" name = "location" id = "location">
</form>

<form name = "display" id = "display" action = "saveentry.php" method = "post">
</form>
```

the PHP code that checks the values is as follows

```
if(empty($_POST['fieldname'])){
    //An error is displayed.
}
```

Any help is highly welcome!

Comment: Why (but why) you have 3 forms?! By default (unless you use AJAX) Only one form will be submitted...

Comment: There's no SUBMIT button or any `type=button` in your HTML. How are you submitting your data?

Comment: Also (at least this is what I do), when I need to process data before submission, I avoid using the default submit mechanism and instead invoke a method of my own. Additionally, you want to check the data **BEFORE** submission, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
onsubmit= "return validation()"
```